rayCaster intersection returns wrong mesh when using custom buffer geometry
This is the code I'm using for creating the meshes:
const depth = 0.1;
const width = 0.017;
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  const v1 = [-0.075 + i * width, 0.06, 0];
  const v2 = [-0.075, 0.06, -depth];
  const v3 = [
    -0.075 + (i + 1) * width,
    0.06,
    -depth,
  ];
  const v4 = [
    -0.075 + (i + 1) * width,
    0.06,
    0,
  ];

  const v5 = [v1[0], 0.15, v1[2]];
  const v6 = [v2[0], 0.15, v2[2]];
  const v7 = [v3[0], 0.15, v3[2]];
  const v8 = [v4[0], 0.15, v4[2]];

  const vertices = new Float32Array([
    //bottom
    ...v1,
    ...v2,
    ...v3,

    ...v3,
    ...v4,
    ...v1,

    //top
    ...v5,
    ...v6,
    ...v7,

    ...v7,
    ...v8,
    ...v5,

    //north
    ...v1,
    ...v4,
    ...v5,

    ...v4,
    ...v5,
    ...v8,

    //east
    ...v1,
    ...v2,
    ...v5,

    ...v5,
    ...v6,
    ...v2,

    //south
    ...v2,
    ...v3,
    ...v6,

    ...v6,
    ...v7,
    ...v3,

    //west
    ...v3,
    ...v4,
    ...v7,

    ...v7,
    ...v8,
    ...v4,
  ]);

  geometry.setAttribute(
    "position",
    new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3)
  );

  const material =
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xff0000,
      side: 2,
      transparent: true,
      opacity: 0,
    });
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    geometry,
    material
  );
  const box = new THREE.BoxHelper(
    mesh,
    0xff0000
  );
  console.log(box);

  scene.add(mesh);
  // scene.add(box);
  meshes.push(mesh);
  boxes.push(box);
  console.log(mesh.id, box.id);
}

This is the final output:

when using pointermove or mousemove event and hovering the mouse over the same box the console prints different ids!!
Any explanations for this matter??
  window.addEventListener("pointermove", () => {
    const intersections =
      raycaster.intersectObjects(meshes, true);
    if (intersections.length > 0) {
      const object = intersections[0];
      for (const element of intersections) {
        element.object.material.opacity = 0;
      }

      console.log(object.object.id);
    }
  });


I'm trying to turn on the material opacity for the box that raycast intersects.

You need get mouse position on screen and setRaycast from this point.
For setting position use
raycaster.setFromCamera(new Vector2(canvasX, canvasY), camera);

To get right position use event information and get position like this.
private getCanvasRelativePosition(event: MouseEvent) {
    const canvas = event.target as HTMLCanvasElement;
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: (event.clientX - rect.left) * canvas.width / rect.width,
      y: (event.clientY - rect.top) * canvas.height / rect.height,
    };
 }

You must do this before you call  raycaster.intersectObjects(meshes, true);

I've just added that piece of code and the problem persists:
mouse.x =
(event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 -
1;
mouse.y =
-(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) *
2 +
1;
// console.log("the pointer ", pointer, mouse);
raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

I expected that to be already done in the animation loop since I'm using React three fiber along with the useThree() hook to get the raycast, pointer, etc:
const {
camera,
gl,
scene,
raycaster,
pointer,
} = useThree();
<Splat
position={[0, 0, 0]}
src={URL}
/>



Hi, i don't three fiber. But did mouse position changing? It's seems strange, it get you something everytime...

of course it's changing. That's the problem. I didn't face any issue when using the raw threejs setup. I believe the issue is related with r3f
